# Performing Client-Side Authentication with Google Sign-In SDK and Azure iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, google-oauth, azure-mobile-services, google-signin

I am having trouble authenticating with Azure through their iOS SDK using the current user's `idToken`. I am pretty sure that it is a problem with the client ID and secret but Microsoft doesn't really have any documentation on this so I don't really know where to start fixing my problem. I think that it may be to do with the Google OAuth2 credentials but I don't know. Any help is appreciated.

Also, here is the login code:

```
    let user: GIDGoogleUser = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser
    let payload: [String: String] = ["access_token": user.authentication.accessToken]

    client.loginWithProvider("Google", token: payload) { (user, error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        print(user)
                    } else {
                        print(error?.localizedDescription)
                        print(error.debugDescription)
                        print(error?.code)
                    }
    }
```

Also I have the app set up with iOS credentials not Web Application credentials. I tried it with Web credentials and it isn't working.

The error localized description and the error code are:

`Optional("The server returned an error.")
Optional(Error Domain=com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorDomain Code=-1301 "The server returned an error." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The server returned an error.})
Optional(-1301)`

Comment: If you turn on Azure App Service Diagnostic logs (level verbose), and then use the Log Stream to view the logs, are there any errors?

Comment: I know I told you to use accessToken instead of idToken.  I'm being told that is the wrong thing.  I'm trying to get confirmation for the proper fields for you.  I'll post a reply once I get confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer back from Microsoft on this and it looks like the SDK does not support client side authentication with Google. The solution that Microsoft engineers gave me was to write my own http request and get a user id that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the serverClientID given by you is wrong.

please put the server client id from webapplication type client id from google developer console.

```
   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "3416174444-rp3463ime417lsjgfat56btr6vssdfsdf.apps.googleusercontent.com" //(client id of iOS type)

   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().serverClientID = "34161794444-no3s7r8o3sa9k416drn9vdvpbbksdfsd9.apps.googleusercontent.com" //(client id of web application type)
```